# Does a computer restart reset the account lockout policy counter?

Tags: windows, windows-10, group-policy, windows-server-2016

Using Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016 with the Account lockout policy set to 3 attempts and 99999 (max) duration. If i locked an account or entered the password wrong 2 times and I then reboot the pc. Will the account unlock or will the counter reset?

Answer (score 2):

No, it will not. Login attempts and lockouts are logged by the domain controller on your domain and are persistent across devices on your domain for domain accounts. Local accounts work the same but are tied to the specific computer.

Comment: How about non-domain?

Comment: @user935892 That's what I meant by "Local accounts".